# Hiding a menu on click outside

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a menu that pops up and at the same time is hidden on a mouse click event on a button but I would like to be able to hide said menu by clicking outside the menu movieclip and its button. Is it possible to accomplish that in as3?

So far this is the solution I found, adapted and have being trying to work with but still not getting anywhere.

```
switchbd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);

function onClickHandler(event : MouseEvent) : void  {
            switch(event.target)
            {
                case switchbd_btn:
                    switchbd.gotoAndStop(2);
                    switchbdIN.start();
                    switchbd_btn.filters = [ONf];
                    break;

                case stage:
                    switchbdOUT.start();
                    switchbd.gotoAndStop(3);
                    switchbd_btn.filters = [OFf];
                    break;
            }
}
```

My original working code :-

```
//////////////////////SWITCH BOARD\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
switchbd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ShowswitchBD);
var switchbdIN:Tween = new Tween (switchbd, "x", Strong.easeOut, 1089.05, 277.85, 1, true);
var switchbdOUT:Tween = new Tween (switchbd, "x", Strong.easeOut, 277.85, 1089.05, 1, true);
var ONf:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter (-1,26,0xCCCCCC,1,2,2,1,3,false,false,false);
var OFf:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter (6,26,0x000000,1,2,2,1,3,false,false,false);

function ShowswitchBD(e:MouseEvent):void {

    if (switchbd.currentFrame != 2)
    {
        switchbd.gotoAndStop(2);
        switchbdIN.start();
        switchbd_btn.filters = [ONf];
}
    else {
        switchbdOUT.start();
        switchbd.gotoAndStop(3);
        switchbd_btn.filters = [OFf];
    }
}
```

switchbd is the menu movieclip, and switchbd_btn is the button.

Comment: when switchdb_btn is clicked, your `onClickHandler` will run twice,  since the stage and the button listener will pick up that same click event. You need to explain better the nature of your menu, and what switchbd is and the other objects referenced in your code

Comment: with mouse event targets,  the target can acutally be a child of the item you added the listener to - so if `switcdb_btn` has children, the event.target could actually refer to one of those.  If you want to be on the safe side, you should do `switchbd_btn.mouseChildren = false;` the same time you add the listener

Comment: so what do you advice I do, by the way switchbd_btn has no child symbols.

Comment: My advise is use two separate click listeners - one that shows the menu attached to whatever button does that (presumably `switchbd_btn`), and one on the stage.     In the button one, show your menu then  do `event.stopPropagation()` so that even doesn't bubble up to the stage.  In the stage one,  check to make the item clicked doesn't originate from your menu,  if not, hide the menu.  Explain what your vars are in your code.  is `switchbd` the menu?  what is `switchbdOUT`? etc.

Comment: i have edited my post adding in my code in its original working state; I'm still pulling my weight in as3 so if you could help simplify your solutions, I'll be grateful. Thnx for your assiatance

Comment: So...is `swtichbd` your menu???  and is frame 2 of it somehow make it visible and frame 3 not?

Comment: yea switchbd is my menu, frame 2 to 3 is were the menu with its content resides, the tween var switchbdOUT is an easing animation that takes the menu off the stage or hides while switchbdIN does the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pattern to accomplish what you're asking. This assumes your menu movieClip is called: `switchbd` and you show/hide it with the button: `switchbd_btn`.

First, add a click listener to your button and create the handler function:

```
switchbd_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu(e:Event):void {
    //the x position should be 277.85 when visible
    if(switchbd.x <= 278){
        hideMenu();
    }else{
        showMenu();
    }
}
```

Now create the show and hide menu functions:

```
function showMenu():void {
    switchbd.gotoAndStop(2); //or however you 'show' it

    switchbdIN.start();
    switchbd_btn.filters = [ONf];

    //since the menu is visible, listen for global mouse clicks to hide it
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hideMenuGlobalClick);
}

function hideMenu():void {
    switchbd.gotoAndStop(3);
    switchbdOUT.start();
    switchbd_btn.filters = [OFf];

    //stop listening for global mouse clicks since the menu is hidden now
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hideMenuGlobalClick);
}

function hideMenuGlobalClick(e:Event):void {
    var target:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject;

    //crawl up the display tree from the item click until there is no parent (stage)
    while(target && target.parent){
        //if the target is the menu or button, exit this function
        if(target == switchbd || target == switcbd_btn){
            return;
        }

        //move on to the next item up the chain
        target = target.parent;
    }

    //if you made it this far, it wasn't the menu that was clicked
    hideMenu();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the, help but I'm getting a compiler error saying "else is unexpected"

Comment: Just a missing bracket (this is all untested code as it just shows the pattern and there could be other typos), I updated it.

Comment: Thanks a billion, it worked; sorry for dragging the problem. I appreciate, now going to have to digg in and educate myself on your code solution cuz it's beginning to look like quantum physics.

Comment: Erm there is one more twist to the menu's showing and hiding: there are 3 frames in the movieclip, the 1st having a stop action  contains a rectangle which is for making it visible on the work stage for quick editing, the 2nd and the 3rd has the menu: the 3rd frame with the menu is there for the purpose of it being visible while its eased off the staged, however using the above conditionals, it works at the first interaction but starts looping at the second interaction, I've tried other condtions but no luck.

Comment: it's a simple solution, more advanced and better would be to use Interfaces to determine which objects have the right to close the menu and which to open it. Then you can implement a system that can manage itself easily.

Comment: @SoloWalker - what do you mean by "starts looping"?  You could listen for the tween finishing and run some code then (like going back to frame 1)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis - by looping, i mean when i click the switchbd_btn, only the showMenu function plays regardless of how many times i click it, except I clicked the stage to hide the menu and once that is done, clicking the button to bring it back up causes the menu to ease into the stage then ease out immediately, plus I did your advice of returning the frame head to 1 using switchbd.gotoAndStop(1); result was not cool. :(

Comment: Maybe you should use the `x` property to determine if the menu should be shown or hidden. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Great. Feel free to give it an upvote if you feel it's worthy.